# Error al obtener el contenido del DIV por id con Javascript

Tags: javascript, div, local-storage

estoy intentado acceder al localStorage para llevar un registro de usuarios, pero al mostrar en otra pagina, me coge bien todos los datos. El problema viene a la hora de mostrarlo que no me pilla bien el div y me da el siguiente error: registro.html:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
at registro.html:17

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro</title>
    <script>
        
        var div=document.getElementById("texto");
        
        for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length;i++){
            var clave=localStorage.key(i);
            var item=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(clave));
            var usuario=item.usuario;
            var inicios=item.inicios;

            var frase="Usuario: "+usuario+" ha iniciado sesion "+inicios+" veces";
            var elemento=document.createElement('p');
            elemento.innerHTML=frase;
            div.appendChild(elemento);
           
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Registro de los usuarios:</h1>
    <div id="texto"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné es un mero despiste, lo que hay que hacer poner el codigo como funcion y ejecutarla en el body con onLoad()

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro</title>
    <script>

        function registrar(){
        
        var div=document.getElementById("texto");
        
        for (var i=0; i<localStorage.length;i++){
            var clave=localStorage.key(i);
            var item=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(clave));
            var usuario=item.usuario;
            var inicios=item.inicios;

            var frase="Usuario: "+usuario+" ha iniciado sesion "+inicios+" veces";
            var elemento=document.createElement('p');
            elemento.innerHTML=frase;
            div.appendChild(elemento);
           
        }

    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="registrar()">
    <h1>Registro de los usuarios:</h1>
    <div id="texto"></div>
</body>
```

Se que es una tontearía pero se lo dejo a alguien que le pueda pasar, sobre todo a los principiantes como yo.

Comment: Una sugerencia: evita usar llamadas en el HTML. Una solución simple en el código que muestras en tu pregunta es mover todo el `script` al final del documento, justo antes de cerrar la etiqueta `</body>`. Ya que para cuando el navegador lea y ejecute el `script` los elementos del documento efectivamente van a existir en el DOM, y no te dará el error de `null`. La idea de no mezclar la vista (`html`) con la lógica (`script`) es mantener separadas las responsabilidades y te será más fácil depurar errores, entre otras ventajas. Saludos